# css class applying after double-click on the asp.net button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i want to apply a class on a asp.net label when validation fails, everything is working fine but it is requiring double-click to apply the class. First click to show the error message of the required field validator and second click applies the class. I need it in one click. Please help

```
<script>
function Validate()
{
    //for textbox
    if ($('#<% =RequiredFieldValidator1.ClientID %>').css('visibility') == 'visible')
    {
        $('#<% =Label1.ClientID %>').addClass('error');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#<% =Label1.ClientID %>').removeClass('error');
    }
 }
</script>  

 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="lbl" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClientClick="Validate()" 
      Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="txt" />
```

Comment: Where are you registering for the event listener ? This is only the function which validates...

Comment: Clear the session/delete browsing history

Answer (score 2):

You need to call your `Validate()` function directly on the page load.
The code is currently doing exactly what you asked it to do, when the validator is visible(after first click), and button is clicked, change color.

Add code like this to call the function onload

```
window.onload = Validate();
```

Comment: Where did you add this code? Will have to be outside your Validate function.